# How can I alter an existent CCK field?

Tags: entities

I have a "first name" field, and I would like to programatically change its attributes. I want to modify this field, but not to create one new field again.

Is it possible?

Comment: What exactly do you want to change ? Drupal 6 or 7 ?

Comment: I am working with drupal 6 and I want to change any attribute, for example, default value or required attribute, but the important is change the field existent(not new field) programatically.

Comment: I suggest be more specific. You can rephrase the question, may be: **how to change the 'default value' and the 'required' attribute of an CCK field existent(not new field) programatically?.**

Answer (score 1):

In this resource http://drupal.org/node/726282 you will find a very useful description about CCK fields and his relation with the function to alter forms, called hook_form_alter(). in few words, you must also use an after_build() function.